# Firefox scroll issue google Picker

Tags: javascript, google-picker

I have integrated Google Picker to my app. Everything works fine as expected. But in firefox I see scroll on x-axis and y-axis.
Doe's anyone faced the same issue?
How can we fix this? Couldn't find answer anywhere.

Comment: Hey, I tested a simple page and it seems to work fine for me. I'd try using the picker in an empty page, to check if it's picker alone or some interaction with your page (for example styling)

Comment: @Martí I looked at another page with different styles and yes, there was no such problem. But so far I can't figure out what is causing the problem

Comment: It's hard to tell without having access to the code and testing myself. What I can recommend is to use Firefox's web development inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I). Looking on the `Style` tab when selecting the various tags, should tell you what styles are being applied.